How to create a reset password feature in symfony 7 with Api Platform
I am using Symfony & Api Platform with docker, and I am trying to create a reset password feature in my application that also sends a mail when its succesfull. I have installed a package called 'CoopTilleulsForgotPasswordBundle'.
I read and followed the instructions from their github https://github.com/coopTilleuls/CoopTilleulsForgotPasswordBundle/tree/main
After setting everything up according to the documentation that is provided.
I tested it with loading 'Fixtures' fake data( symfony console doctrine:fixtures:load ).
And then I used Postman to try it out with fake data that had been loaded to my database thanks to fixtures.
But When I send a Post request with a body,
[email => fake_email@from_database.com]
to the route: 'localhost::80/api/forgot-password/'
I receive: 400 Bad request '{"message":"No parameter sent."}'
This is kind if confusing because I did not really understand what it meant.
I hoped and expected some token back as verification that it found the email.
I am not to familiar with Symfony but I really want to try it out for the project I am working on.
As I mentioned It confused me as I didnt understood what I should do to solve this.
I tried adding a parameter with a provider from 'config/packages/coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.yaml' when sending the email

# config/packages/coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.yaml
coop_tilleuls_forgot_password:
    providers: 
        customer:
            default: true
            password_token:
                class: 'App\Entity\PasswordToken' # required
                expires_in: '1 day'
                user_field: 'user'
                serialization_groups: []
            user:
                class: 'App\Entity\User' # required
                email_field: 'email'

According to the documentation the key should be 'FP-provider' with value of a provider.
FP-provider => customer
But I am still getting the same message 'No parameter found'.
I then tried create a GetTokenController
namespace App\Controller\Api;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
final class GetTokenController
{
    public function __invoke(): Response
    {
        // return new Response('', Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
        return new Response('Testing', Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}

At the moment I am kind of stuck trying to create api endpoint(s) that provide a reset feature in my application.
Config > Packages > Security.yaml
access_control:
        - { path: '^/api/forgot-password', role: PUBLIC_ACCESS }

SRC > Entity > passwordToken.php
<?php
namespace App\Entity;
use CoopTilleuls\ForgotPasswordBundle\Entity\AbstractPasswordToken;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
#[ORM\Entity]
class PasswordToken extends AbstractPasswordToken
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer', nullable: false)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'AUTO')]
    private ?int $id = null;
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false, name: 'user_id')]
    private $user;
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function setUser($user): void
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}

Config > Packages > coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.yaml
coop_tilleuls_forgot_password:
    providers: 
        customer:
            default: true
            password_token:
                class: 'App\Entity\PasswordToken' # required
                expires_in: '1 day'
                user_field: 'user'
                serialization_groups: []
            user:
                class: 'App\Entity\User' # required
                email_field: 'email'
                password_field: 'password'


Config > Routes > coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.yaml
coop_tilleuls_forgot_password:
    resource: "@CoopTilleulsForgotPasswordBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
    # prefix:   /forgot_password
    # resource: .
    type: coop_tilleuls_forgot_password
    prefix: '/api/forgot-password'

Update: 1
Thanks to VdevS comment/references I had a better look at how the
package works (thanks VdevS)
I am able to authenticate if the user is not logged in. But havent managed to send a token to the mail.
So far I have editted the following in my services.yaml
CoopTilleuls\ForgotPasswordBundle\Manager\ForgotPasswordManager:
        class: CoopTilleuls\ForgotPasswordBundle\Manager\ForgotPasswordManager
        arguments:
            $passwordTokenManager: '@coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.manager.password_token'
            # $manager: '@coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.manager.doctrine'
            # $userClass: App\Entity\Tuser

    CoopTilleuls\ForgotPasswordBundle\Provider\ProviderChainInterface:
        class: CoopTilleuls\ForgotPasswordBundle\Provider\ProviderChainInterface
    
    coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.controller.update_password:
        class: CoopTilleuls\ForgotPasswordBundle\Controller\UpdatePassword
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

And this is how my 'EventSubscriber/ForgotPasswordEventSubscriber.php' Looks like
final class ForgotPasswordEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(private readonly MailerInterface $mailer, private readonly Environment $twig,private JWTEncoderInterface $jwtEncoder,)
    {
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            // KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'onKernelRequest',
            CreateTokenEvent::class => 'onCreateToken',
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        if (!$event->isMainRequest() || !str_starts_with($event->getRequest()->get('_route'), 'coop_tilleuls_forgot_password')) {
            return;
        }

        // dd($event->getRequest());

        $extractor = new AuthorizationHeaderTokenExtractor(
            'Bearer',
            'Authorization'
        );

        $token = $extractor->extract($event->getRequest());

        if($token != false) {
            throw new AuthenticationException('Authentication attempt!');
        }
    }


    public function onCreateToken(CreateTokenEvent $event): void
    {
        dd($event);

        $passwordToken = $event->getPasswordToken();
        $user = $passwordToken->getUser();

        $message = (new Email())
            ->from('project@example.com')
            ->to($user->getEmail())
            ->cc('xxxxx@xxxx.xx')
            ->subject('Reset your password')
            ->html($this->twig->render(
                'App:ResetPassword:mail.html.twig',
                [
                    'reset_password_url' => sprintf('https://www.example.com/forgot-password/%s', $passwordToken->getToken()),
                ]
            ));
        // $this->mailer->send($message);
        
        dd('message is send');
    }
...

Inside the 'onKernelRequest' I check if there is a token, if not then there is no user registered.
When I try to create a token and send, By using getSusbcribedEvents and returning: CreateTokenCreateEvent::class => 'onCreateToken'
I get a response: 204 no Content
Also
So I am trying to figure out how to get it to fire the onCreateToken function
Update: 2 (my Solution)
The weird thing is that I woke up next morning, turned on my computer and tried the onCreateToken function which creates the token and sends the email.
Suddenly worked I could see the dump function working. Whch I couldnt see previously, and I continued on the code and testing with Postman and finally it just worked.
What I did after the function onCreateToken did what it suppose to do:

White list Ip address (in my case on mailgun)

configure the mailer.yaml (to see all errors from the eventSubscriber)
like:


   - framework:
       mailer:
           dsn: '%env(MAILER_DSN)%'
           message_bus: false <-- to see errors


Did you try the reset-password-bundle ?
composer require symfonycasts/reset-password-bundle
symfony console make:reset-password  

source : https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/passwords.html#reset-password

Yes sir,
I did tried it but I couldnt figure out how to connect to correspond with react frontend. Thats why I tried to accomplish it with CoopTilleulsForgotPasswordBundle because it is designed for API Rest applications

the User isn't authenticated ?
https://github.com/coopTilleuls/CoopTilleulsForgotPasswordBundle/blob/main/docs/user_not_authenticated.md
Have you write password CreateToken like this : https://github.com/coopTilleuls/CoopTilleulsForgotPasswordBundle/blob/main/docs/usage.md ?
And with postman, send a JSON POST
{
"email": "foo@example.com"
}

And SymfonyCast/reset-password-bundle work well with api rest :)

Thanks for the comment,
I think I forgot to added it as a service, after adding it to services:
I am able to see my  "eventSubscriber" working through Postman
It is not fully working yet. Still working to get it working

Thanks @VDevS I managed to check if the user is not logged in, But not able to fire the onCreateToken function, and send a mail.
I am now trying to read some forums/articels to expand my knowledge about services and eventSubscriber...Thanks so far
